# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' ,

Tags: python, regex, cisco, netmiko

I am trying to fetch the cisco version by Netmiko.

```
import re
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

iosv_l3 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': 'my ip',
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'secret': 'enable password'
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**iosv_l3)
net_connect.enable()
output = net_connect.send_command('show version | include flash')
print(output)
x = re.search(r'["]flash:/(.*)["]',output).group(1)
print(x)
net_connect.disconnect()
```

The Netmiko can SSH to Cisco equipment successfully. I can see the output from print(output):

```
System image file is "flash:c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin"
```

However, the code results in an error:

```
x = re.search(r'["]flash:/(.*)["]',output).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I created a test file to test regex:

```
import re
txt = "System image file is \"flash:/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin\""
txt = re.search(r'["]flash:/(.*)["]',txt).group(1)
print(txt)
```

The test print "c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin" correctly.

Comment: `re.search` returned no results

Comment: You are searching for flash:/c... but there is no /

Comment: @PowellQuiring   you are right.....sorry about that

Comment: Try just `r'"flash:([^"]+)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `re.match(..)` returns `Match` object (which has `.group(x)` methods and etc) or `None` in case if the match was not found. In your case the error means that was returned `None` ;)

Ok, it means that regex pattern doesn't work for the data tested. I've debugged your both cases and I've been noticed that in the first script you apply the pattern to `is "flash:c2900-` but in the second example you are testing the regex against `file is \"flash:/c2900` where between `flash:` and `c2900` we have an extra `/` which doesn't exist in the first example.

Ok, so there are 2 ways to fix it - if you want to work it with and without `/` using the same regex, it will be this way

```
import re

output = 'System image file is "flash:c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin"'
print(re.search(r'"flash:/?(.*)"', output).group(1))

output = 'System image file is "flash:/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin"'
print(re.search(r'"flash:/?(.*)"', output).group(1))
```

using optional regex matching (`?`).

If you want to work only with `/` or without you can use these examples.

```
import re

output = 'System image file is "flash:c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin"'
print(re.search(r'"flash:(.*)"', output).group(1))

output = 'System image file is "flash:/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin"'
print(re.search(r'"flash:/(.*)"', output).group(1))
```

Comment: So the advice is to change the regex and not check if it matched ?

Comment: I think for you this mask will work, so you can use it and forget about the bug :)

print(re.search(r'"flash:/?(.*)"', output).group(1))

and, of course, that is a good idea to check if it matched or not using `if not re.search(..): raise ValueError("no match found")` and so on

Comment: If seriously wanting a specific result using an externally generated target string expecting a match without checking is bad code practice. `if not re.search(..):` requires an `else :  re.search(..)` to get the match object. Doing the same regex twice is unnecessary

Comment: of course, you should use a variable for the match object. that's obvious :) I've used `if ...` just to say what we are checking, not how

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> txt = "System image file is \"flash:/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin"
>>> txt = re.search(r'["]flash:/(.*)["]',txt).group(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
>>> print(txt)
System image file is "flash:/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin
>>>
>>>
```

Apparently *`output`* does not contain what is anticipated.
There was no match. The object is a NULL one.

Test the match first  :

```
import re
txt = "System image file is \"flash:/c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.156-3.M6.bin\""
match = re.search(r'["]flash:/(.*)["]',txt)
if ( match ) :
    print(match.group(1))
else :
    print("No match")
```